# Sublime Text 3 subl command not working in Windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, command-line, sublimetext3, command-prompt

when I run the subl command, it just pauses for a moment and doesn't give me any feedback as to what happened and doesn't open. I am currently on windows 10 running the latest sublime text 3 build. I already copied my subl.exe from my sublime text 3 directory to my system32 directory. What am I missing? I've tried subl.exe ., subl.exe detect.py, subl, subl.exe

Please help me with this setup

Comment: Instead of copying `subl.exe`, try adding your Sublime Text installation directory to your PATH. For security reasons, you shouldn't be adding **anything** to `system32`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you invoke `subl.exe` via an absolute path then it works.

```
> "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe"
```

Assuming the above works, then the location of `subl.exe` can be added to the system path so that there is no need to specify the absolute path.

Go to `Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings` and add `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` to the `PATH` environment variable.

Check that the `PATH` variable does not already contain the path to `subl.exe` so to avoid adding it twice.

You essentially are going to append `;C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3` to the `PATH` variable. *Note the `;` which is a path separator.*

**You may need to restart Windows for the change to take effect.**

See [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) for in depth information on `PATH` and other environment variables in general.

Answer (score 1):

You can add gitbash alias like below
open a gitbash terminal and type
    alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe"

then try subl . from gitbash

you can also add permanent alias for git bash like below

1. Go to: C:\Users\ [youruserdirectory] \
2. make a .bash_profile file
3. open it with text editor
4. add the alias .

   alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 3/subl.exe"

Answer (score 1):

After adding a path environmental variable, you have just to type `subl.exe` in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a link from your installation directory to the System32 directory like:

```
mklink c:\Windows\System32\subl.exe "c:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\subl.exe"
```

Comment: NO. You shouldn't be modifying `System32` in *any* way!

Answer (score 0):

After adding the path variable, restart your PC, worked like a charm.