# Subl command in windows 10 is recognized but does not open sublime text 3

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-10, sublimetext3

I have a problem where i got sublime3 installed on my Windows 10. Folder is added to the env path `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3;`. And still when entering `subl` in cmd  what happens is command is accepted but nothing happens...
when i enter in cmd : `subl -help` i get out:

```
Sublime Text build 3211

Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         Edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   Open the given directories

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:        Keep the application activated after closing the file
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

So it is like it does work yet it doesn't open. I tried also `subl -n` with the same result and opening a file with `subl file.py`

I did restarted computer.
Probelm is similar to this one: [Sublime Text 3 subl command not working in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691547/sublime-text-3-subl-command-not-working-in-windows-10) but soultion provided does not work. Although I didn't copy subl.exe to system32 dir since i had already added folder with sublime to the env user path.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the error. I must have pasted subl.exe to my sys32 folder long time ago. What was happening, my that the file frome sys32 would open instead of the one in program files. Still dont understand why it wouldn't work...

Comment: Is your `sys32` directory in the PATH variable before the `Program Files` directory?

Comment: Just as a general rule: you should *never* put *anything* into `System32` or any other system directory just to add it to your PATH. Open the Control Panel app and search for "path" instead, there'll be an option to edit your environment variables, which is what you want. Make sure to restart CMD or Powershell after you do that to reload the changes.